# <span> position relative to parent container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `<span>` to address some tabular data which I want to position relative to the container edge, the container being a WordPress Toggle.

I have tried this in CSS

```
.px_update_number {
    position: relative;left: 2em;
}
.px_update_date {
    position: relative;left: 4em;
}
.px_update_notes {
    position: relative;left: 6em;
}
```

and this in the HTML

```
<span class="px_update_number">SP1</span><span class="px_update_date">2015.04.16</span>
```

and the spacing is relative to the "column" before. If I use Absolute in the CSS then alignment is relative to the page edge, not the Toggle. And I need the toggle because there is going to be a ton of data, and at any one time someone is going to be looking only for a very specific bit.

So, am I just implementing this wrong? Or am I barking up an empty tree and I need to reconsider some aspect of what i am trying to do?

OK, so nesting s helped, but I am still having an issue. I would expect this

```
<span class="px_update_number">#<span class="px_update_date">DATE<span class="px_revitupdate_build">BUILD</span></span></span>
<span class="px_update_number">FCS<span class="px_update_date">2016.04.18<span class="px_revitupdate_build">20160225_1515</span></span></span>
```

to produce a header row with good alignment. But instead the alignments are off. Despite now getting multiple rows of the actual data to seemingly work right.

And, not sure I have it right yet, as this

```
<span class="px_update_number">R2<span class="px_update_date">2015.10.22<span class="px_revitupdate_build">20151007_0715</span><span class="px_revitupdate_notes">All Updates after R2 are subscription only</span></span></span>
<span class="px_update_number"><s>1</s><span class="px_update_date">2015.12.17<span class="px_revitupdate_build">20151209_0715<span class="px_revitupdate_notes">Expired</span></span></span></span>
```

still shows a misalignment in the second column, as if it's being aligned to the right side of the first column, not the left, so when the number of characters in the first column changes it throws everything off.

link to [MCVE](http://www.pragmaticpraxis.com/broken-columns/)

Comment: You can do it if the <span>s are nested, otherwise you might need javascript.

Comment: Well dang, I was thinking I had to NOT nest them to keep them from relating to each other. But I am still seeing some odd behavior, as appended to the original post.

Comment: What is the Toggle?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ah, maybe the toggle is a theme thing, not a wordpress thing. It's basically an accordion container. You can twirl open a section, then close it and open another. The toggle is located such that the white space around it expands when the page is widened, thus the need for relative, not absolute to page edge. As for a MCVE, if the toggle is actually theme based then I guess I need an example on a publicly available page of my sire? I don't see how I could paste anything meaningful in a post.

Comment: Assuming a link is a valid approach, I am adding a link to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span` tags are inline by default. But `left` settings (as well as top, bottom and right) only affect block elements (which also need to have a defined `position` other than `static`). So in your CSS those `left` settings do nothing.

As a quick fix you can add `display: inline-block` to the CSS classes you posted above.

ADDED AFTER COMMENT:

Here's a codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWEEbg

`position: relative;` plus a left setting will move the element by the given value. But the space kept free for the element is `not` moved. So if you give your first element `left: 2em;` and the second element also `left: 2em;`, it will look as if there is no space between them.

So if you want the second element to be 4em right of the first one, you actually have to give it `left: 6em;` (as in my codepen)

2nd ADDITION:

Here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLYYXz  I used `margin-left`instead of `left`, which  does what you probably want: It creates space between the elements, without the complication of the `left` setting as described above.

3rd ADDITION:

Cange the `position: relative` to `absolute` and again use `left` (not `margin-left`). Now the distances are measured in relation to the parent elements upper left corner, so the second element will stay at the same position regardless of the contents of the first one:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grXopb

If all that is in a parent container, it will have to have `position: relative:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBPpqa

Comment: OK, that makes sense (I am still learning). But I am still missing something. I tried addin inline-block, both before and after the position, and still no joy.

Comment: Johannes, I am seeing it. If I change the number from SP1 to just 1, the date shifts to the left, rather than staying put. Tried it on your code pen as well. So, with this in the code pend, the alignment is lost.
<div><span class="px_update_number">1</span><span class="px_update_date">2015.04.16</span></div>
<div><span class="px_update_number">SP1</span><span class="px_update_date">2015.04.16</span></div>

Comment: one more solution added to my answer, see above

Comment: BTW: There are serveral solutions for this kind of thing. It seems you are actually after a table-like solution: Or you could  use inline-blocks with fixed widths within block containers. Of floated elements with fixed withs and `clear: left` on every first element in a line. Lots of choices... ;-)

Comment: Johannnes, the thing with that third option is that Absolute then pulls everything left to the page edge. The alignment between elements works, but the alignment with the parent container is lost. I updated my "real" example to show this. but it's progress!

Comment: The parent container will have to have `position: relative` in that case. (Your code didin't contain a parent element...) New codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBPpqa

Comment: Boom! I did a minimal container and that seems to be doing the trick in my little live example. Will see what i break when I try to scale that up to full data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use table tag, or grid layout to solve your problem.
So your layout would relate to column width, but not to left element.

Comment: Latvian, I started trying to get tables to work, and had no joy there either. And I found a number of Stack Overflow answers suggesting not to use tables for layout, only to use tables when you actually want the lines around the table.

Comment: You should use table only when you need table. In your task - you got table structure. (if you don't wanna use table, you can use grid layout for same purposes.)